# PHP foreach() - invalid argument from MySQLi query?

Tags: php, arrays

I am struggling with my `mysqli` query array. I am querying Log-case reference numbers from the database and need to check whether any reference has a folder with the same reference number containing any files. If yes, I have to `scandir` the folder content and attach each file to a mail via `$mail->AddAttachment()`.

This is simple code and I use it in other parts the of website just fine, but here it throws an `invalid argument` error while trying to read the array.

PHP:-

```
// query records submitted within the last 24 hours
$sql = "SELECT LogID FROM qci_dmlog_data GROUP BY LogID";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die('<p>Query to get data from qci_dmlog_data table failed: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli) . '</p>');

// define path to attachment folder
$log_folder = "../attachments/";


while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

print($row['LogID']);

    foreach ($row['LogID'] as $case) {

      // check if folder with case reference exists or not
      if (file_exists($log_folder.$case)) {
        $files = scandir($log_folder.$case);
        $n = 1;

        // ignore . and .. folders
        foreach($files as $file) {      
          if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;

          // get file extension and rename filename only
          $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          $newName = str_replace($file,$n.'.'.$extension,$file);
          rename($log_folder.$case."/".$file, $log_folder.$case."/".$newName);

          // attach to email
          $mail->addAttachment($log_folder.$case."/".$newName);
          echo "Attachment: $newName<br>";
          $n++;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong here please?

Thanks

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: @Anant it outputs the correct LogID but simultaneously throws a `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ... ` error

Comment: @C0dekid it outputs the correct LogID number, but still throws an invalid argument error

Comment: @Armitage2k  is `$row['LogID']` is an array? i don't think so

Comment: @Anant it should be since I have 2000 records in my DB. but assuming it isnt, how would I do a `foreach` for a string then?

Comment: @Armitage2k   `$case = $row['LogID'];`  and then remove first foreach only.that's it and check

Comment: @Anant thanks mate, its time for me to sleep, silly silly scriptkiddy mistake here -.- Have a beer on me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that  `$row['LogID']` is not an array,it's an string. So you need to remove first `foreach()` from your code like below:-

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$case = $row['LogID']);

      // check if folder with case reference exists or not
      if (file_exists($log_folder.$case)) {
        $files = scandir($log_folder.$case);
        $n = 1;

        // ignore . and .. folders
        foreach($files as $file) {      
          if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;

          // get file extension and rename filename only
          $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          $newName = str_replace($file,$n.'.'.$extension,$file);
          rename($log_folder.$case."/".$file, $log_folder.$case."/".$newName);

          // attach to email
          $mail->addAttachment($log_folder.$case."/".$newName);
          echo "Attachment: $newName<br>";
          $n++;
        }
      }
}
```

Note:- check all other variables like `$log_folder` are already set and have correct values.Thanks

Comment: Armitage2k  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have one value inside $row['LogID'], the argument is invalid. With the foreach loop, you can go through an array element by element. Because you are inside a while loop, fetching every single LogID, you could just erase the foreach, because you only get one element per looping the while loop.

This should work for you:

```
// query records submitted within the last 24 hours
$sql = "SELECT LogID FROM qci_dmlog_data GROUP BY LogID";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die('<p>Query to get data from qci_dmlog_data table failed: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli) . '</p>');

// define path to attachment folder
$log_folder = "../attachments/";


while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

print($row['LogID']);

$case = $row['LogID'];

// check if folder with case reference exists or not
if (file_exists($log_folder.$case)) {
    $files = scandir($log_folder.$case);
    $n = 1;

    // ignore . and .. folders
    foreach($files as $file) {      //IS FILES AN ARRAY?
      if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;

      // get file extension and rename filename only
      $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $newName = str_replace($file,$n.'.'.$extension,$file);
      rename($log_folder.$case."/".$file, $log_folder.$case."/".$newName);

      // attach to email
      $mail->addAttachment($log_folder.$case."/".$newName);
      echo "Attachment: $newName<br>";
      $n++;      
  }
}
```

Correct usage of foreach:

```
foreach($array as $arrayElement) {

}
```